# Using R to download zipped data file, extract, and import data

Tags: r, connection, zip, r-faq

@EZGraphs on Twitter writes:
"Lots of online csvs are zipped. Is there a way to download, unzip the archive, and load the data to a data.frame using R? #Rstats"

I was also trying to do this today, but ended up just downloading the zip file manually.

I tried something like:

```
fileName <- "http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip"
con1 <- unz(fileName, filename="a1.dat", open = "r")
```

but I feel as if I'm a long way off.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Did it work? If so, why would you still feel that you're a long way off?

Comment: @Frustrated... Nope. the code in my question does not work. See answers below.

Comment: Added solution using library(archive) below - for me this was the fastest option & it also allows reading in a particular csv file within the archive without having to unzip the whole archive first.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Zip archives are actually more a 'filesystem' with content metadata etc. See `help(unzip)` for details.  So to do what you sketch out above you need to

1. Create a temp. file name (eg `tempfile()`)
2. Use `download.file()` to fetch the file into the temp. file
3. Use `unz()` to extract the target file from temp. file
4. Remove the temp file via `unlink()`

which in code (thanks for basic example, but this is simpler) looks like

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip",temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "a1.dat"))
unlink(temp)
```

Compressed (`.z`) or gzipped (`.gz`) or bzip2ed (`.bz2`) files are *just the file* and those you can read directly from a connection.  So get the data provider to use that instead :)

Comment: Dirk, would you mind expanding on how to extract data from a `.z` archive? I can read from a url connection with `readBin(url(x, "rb"), 'raw', 99999999)`, but how would I extract the contained data? The `uncompress` package has been removed from CRAN - is this possible in base R (and if so, is it restricted to *nix systems?)? Happy to post as a new question if appropriate.

Comment: See `help(gzfile)` -- I was thinking that the gzip protocol may now uncompress (stone old) .z files too now that the patent has long expired. It may not.  Who uses .z anyways?  The 1980s called, they want their compression back ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I can't get it to work, so perhaps it's unsupported after all. The Australian Bureau of Meteorology provides some of their data as .z, unfortunately!

Comment: FYI It does not work with `readRDS()` (at least for me). From what I can tell, the file needs to be in a kind of file that you can read with `read.table()`.

Comment: To echo the comment by @jessi , it doesn't work with readxl::read_excel() either

Comment: you'll also want to close the connection. R can only have 125 open at once. Something like con <- unz(temp, "a1.dat"); data <- read.table(con); close(con);

Comment: Using library(archive) one can also do read_csv(archive_read("http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip", file = 1), col_types = cols()) which I find more convenient (it also supports all major  archive formats & is faster than untar or unz I believe). To unzip everything one can use archive_extract("http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip", dir=XXX). So for me that would be the preferred option.

Comment: Sure.  Add-on packages are great and and often offer complementary functionality _today_. But my answer was written _twelve years ago_ and it is nice that it already worked then, or eleven years before `archive` appeared.  And likely will work for years to come whereas add-on packages sometimes disappear, or change.

Answer (score 35):

Just for the record, I tried translating Dirk's answer into code :-P

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip",temp)
con <- unz(temp, "a1.dat")
data <- matrix(scan(con),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
unlink(temp)
```

Comment: Don't use `scan()`; you can use `read.table()` et al directly on a connection.  See my edited answer,

Answer (score 23):

I used CRAN package "downloader" found at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/downloader/index.html . Much easier.

```
download(url, dest="dataset.zip", mode="wb") 
unzip ("dataset.zip", exdir = "./")
```

Comment: I just use utils::unzip no need for the downlaoder package for me

Comment: as of 2019 - I had to say exdir='.'

Answer (score 15):

For Mac (and I assume Linux)...

If the zip archive contains a single file, you can use the bash command `funzip`, in conjuction with `fread` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("curl http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip | funzip")
```

In cases where the archive contains multiple files, you can use `tar` instead to extract a specific file to stdout:

```
dt <- fread("curl http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip | tar -xf- --to-stdout *a1.dat")
```

Comment: when I tried your solution for multiple files, I'm getting an error that `File is empty:`

Comment: Did not work form either. 
The only one that worked was `read_csv(archive_read("http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip", file = 1), col_types = cols())`  below.  Also, The only way to read .zip directly from shinyapps.io

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example that works for files which cannot be read in with the `read.table` function. This example reads a .xls file.

```
url <-"https://www1.toronto.ca/City_Of_Toronto/Information_Technology/Open_Data/Data_Sets/Assets/Files/fire_stns.zip"

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()

download.file(url, temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
data <- read_xls(file.path(temp2, "fire station x_y.xls"))

unlink(c(temp, temp2))
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `library(archive)` one can also read in a particular csv file within the archive, without having to UNZIP it first; `read_csv(archive_read("http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip", file = 1), col_types = cols())`
which I find more convenient & is faster.

It also supports all major  archive formats & is quite a bit faster than the base R untar or unz - it supports tar, ZIP, 7-zip, RAR, CAB, gzip, bzip2, compress, lzma, xz & uuencoded files.

To unzip everything one can use `archive_extract("http://www.newcl.org/data/zipfiles/a1.zip", dir=XXX)`

This works on all platforms & given the superior performance for me would be the preferred option.

Comment: This is great answer ! - It allows me to read a remote .zip file  from shinyapp, which none of other answers can do. 
Also, a tip: You do need to use `readr::read_csv(...)` here, and with `readr::cols()` .  I tried `data.table::fread(...)` and it did not work.

Comment: This was the simplest approach for me too! Several of the others also didn't work for the zip file I was trying to open.

Comment: @tnt glad it worked well for you! tell the OP to check this answer as the best one if he likes... Checked answers on this site are often heavily outdated...

Answer (score 6):

To do this using data.table, I found that the following works. Unfortunately, the link does not work anymore, so I used a link for another data set.

```
library(data.table)
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://www.bls.gov/tus/special.requests/atusact_0315.zip", temp)
timeUse <- fread(unzip(temp, files = "atusact_0315.dat"))
rm(temp)
```

I know this is possible in a single line since you can pass bash scripts to `fread`, but I am not sure how to download a .zip file, extract, and pass a single file from that to `fread`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code. It works for me:

```
unzip(zipfile="<directory and filename>",
      exdir="<directory where the content will be extracted>")
```

Example:

```
unzip(zipfile="./data/Data.zip",exdir="./data")
```

Answer (score 1):

`rio()` would be very suitable for this - it uses the file extension of a file name to determine what kind of file it is, so it will work with a large variety of file types. I've also used `unzip()` to list the file names within the zip file, so its not necessary to specify the file name(s) manually.

```
library(rio)

# create a temporary directory
td <- tempdir()

# create a temporary file
tf <- tempfile(tmpdir=td, fileext=".zip")

# download file from internet into temporary location
download.file("http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/BasicCompanyData-part1.zip", tf)

# list zip archive
file_names <- unzip(tf, list=TRUE)

# extract files from zip file
unzip(tf, exdir=td, overwrite=TRUE)

# use when zip file has only one file
data <- import(file.path(td, file_names$Name[1]))

# use when zip file has multiple files
data_multiple <- lapply(file_names$Name, function(x) import(file.path(td, x)))

# delete the files and directories
unlink(td)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following worked for me. These steps come from BTD's YouTube video, [Managing Zipfile's in R](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcW8ZFs5sGA):

```
zip.url <- "url_address.zip"

dir <- getwd()

zip.file <- "file_name.zip"

zip.combine <- as.character(paste(dir, zip.file, sep = "/"))

download.file(zip.url, destfile = zip.combine)

unzip(zip.file)
```