# Extract certain files from .zip

Tags: r, unzip

Is there a way to selectively extract from a `.zip` archive those files with names matching a pattern?

For example, if I want to use all `.csv` files from the archive and ignore other files.

Current approach:

```
zipped_file_names <- unzip('some_archive.zip') # extracts everything, captures file names
csv_nms <-  grep('csv', zipped_file_names, ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
library('data.table')
comb_tbl <- rbindlist(lapply(csv_nms,  function(x) cbind(fread(x, sep=',', header=TRUE, 
                                                               stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
                                                         file_nm=x) ), fill=TRUE )
```

Instead of just selecting which ones to read (`csv_nms`), I'm looking for a way to choose which ones to extract in the first place.

I'm currently on v3.2.2 (Windows).

Comment: You can use `list=TRUE` argument of `unzip` to get a list of the file names, and then loop through the ones you want to extract

Comment: Doh.  After reading `?unzip` more closely, I see: `list 
If TRUE, list the files and extract none. The equivalent of unzip -l.`  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to comment from  @user20650.

Use two calls to `unzip`.  First with `list=TRUE` just to get the `$Name` for the files.  Second with `files=` to extract only the files whose names match the pattern.

```
  zipped_csv_names <- grep('\\.csv$', unzip('some_archive.zip', list=TRUE)$Name, 
                           ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
  unzip('some_archive.zip', files=zipped_csv_names)
  comb_tbl <- rbindlist(lapply(zipped_csv_names,  
                               function(x) cbind(fread(x, sep=',', header=TRUE,
                                                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
                                                 file_nm=x)), fill=TRUE )
```