# R: Reading a csv from within 2 zip folders

Tags: r, zip, read.csv

I am working under some unfortunate circumstances, and need to read in a csv file from within 2 zip folders. What I mean by this is that the file path looks something like this:

`//path/folder1.zip/folder2.zip/wanttoread.csv`

I tried mimicking the slick work of this problem found here: [Extract certain files from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870863/extract-certain-files-from-zip) , but have had no luck so far. Specifically, when I ran something similar on my end, I got an error message reading

```
Error in fread(x, sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
embedded nul in string:
```

followed by a bunch of encoded nonsense.

Any ideas on how to handle this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tempdir()`:

```
temp<-tempdir(check = TRUE) #Create temporary directory to extract into

unzip("folder1.zip",exdir = temp) #Unzip outer archive to temp directory

unzip(file.path(temp,"folder2.zip"), #Use file.path to generate the path to the inner archive
      exdir = file.path(temp,"temp2")) #Extract to a subfolder inside temp
                                       #This covers the case when the outer archive might also have a file named wanttoread.csv

list.files(file.path(temp,"temp2")) #We can see the .csv file is now there
#[1] "wanttoread.csv"

read.csv(file.path(temp,"temp2","wanttoread.csv")) #Read it in
#   Var1         Var2
#1 Hello obewanjacobi
```

Comment: This is a very interesting method, and actually kind of perfect for my given scenario, as I'm actually looping through zip folders of zip folders. This makes it so that I just do 1 loop, unzip everything into the temp directory, and then can loop a second time within that directory (rather than a loop in a loop). 

So 1 more question regarding this method, is there a way for R to automatically delete the temporary directories made once we're done here? That way I'm not wasting space on my PC?

Comment: for the record, I attempted to use file.remove to remove the entire directory, but R said that it didn't have permission to. Should note this is my work pc I'm running this on, so it's entirely possible that this may be un-doable, but I'd like to give it a shot. I'm able to manually delete the folder myself though.