# Error code 1 when trying to unzip bin.gz file

Tags: r

I was following along [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044808/using-r-to-download-gzipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) SO post on how to download and unzip a file.

```
url <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
file <- basename(url)
download.file(url, file)

tmpdir <- tempdir()
untar(file, compressed = 'gzip', exdir = tmpdir)
```

Everything runs fine in the above block except the last line which returns

```
> untar(file, compressed = 'gzip', exdir = tmpdir)
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Warning message:
In untar(file, compressed = "gzip", exdir = tmpdir) :
  ‘/usr/bin/tar -xf 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz' -C '/var/folders/ll/g08vjcnd33vdhf250bbg9230fdw13f/T//RtmpAICV5a'’ returned error code 1
```

How can I unzip GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz after downloading it?

Comment: Are you sure it's a tar file? If it isn't, I'm guessing `untar` won't work on it. Try `R.utils::gunzip`, which is probably better suited

Comment: agree with @Camille...it looks like you have a binary file (not a tarball) that was compressed with gzip. you can decompress it with `gunzip`.

Comment: @camille gunzip did the trick, thank oyu