# Extract bz2 file in R

Tags: r, bzip2

I have bunch of `.csv.bz2` files, which i have to download, extract, and read in R.
I downloaded the file and want to extract it to current working directory, then read it.
`unz(filename,filename.csv)` but it does not seem to work. How can I do that?

I heard somewhere that bzfiles can be read directly without decompressing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use any of these two commands:

1. `read.csv()`command: with this command you can directly supply your compressed filename containing csv file.

   `read.csv("file.csv.bz2")`
2. `read.table()` command: This command is generic version of `read.csv()` command. You can set delimiters and others options that `read.csv()` automatically sets. You don't need to uncompress the file separately. This command does it automatically for you.

   `read.csv("file.csv.bz2", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",...)`

Answer (score 27):

Like this:

```
readcsvbz2file <- read.csv(bzfile("file.csv.bz2"))
```

Comment: `bzfile()`is not necessary, `read.csv()` can handle compressed files automatically. So it's just `read.csv("file.csv.bz2")`. [Here is an example](http://rpubs.com/Noseshine/77486) (first section "Loading the Data").

Comment: bzipfile() is a more general solution because it useful for other formats. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of the super fast `fread` which has built-in support for bz2-compressed files

```
require(data.table)
fread("file.csv.bz2")
```

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you need to type:

```
library(R.utils)
bunzip2("dataset.csv.bz2", "dataset.csv", remove = FALSE, skip = TRUE)

dataset <- read.csv("dataset.csv")
```

See documentation here: [bunzip2 {R.utils}](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/R.utils/docs/bunzip2).

Answer (score 4):

According to [read.table](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) description, one can read [a compressed file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) directly.

```
read.table("file.csv.bz2")
```