# How to extract and read a bzip2ed hdf5 in a zipped file in R?

Tags: r, hdf5, bzip2, hdf

I would like to read a hdf5 file in a zipped file. The issue here is that this hdf5 file is also double zipped as a bzip2ed (.bz2) file.

Please refer to the figure shown below.

The zip file is `"g2_BIOPAR_SWI_201012250000_GLOBE_ASCAT_V2_0_0.ZIP"`.

The target bz2 file is `"g2_BIOPAR_SWI_201012250000_GLOBE_ASCAT_V2_0_0.h5.bz2"`.

Could someone show me some tips or guidances in how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at this question:

[Extract bz2 file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948777/extract-bz2-file-in-r)

It explains how to read a`.bz2` file and I think the last answer is the right one for you,; or just type `?bzfile`.
After that for hdf5 files you can give a look at rhdf5 package from Bioncoductor; here is the link:

http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html