# r function unzip error 1 in extracting from zip file

Tags: r, unzip

Environment:
Windows 7 OS
RStudio Version 0.99.491

I have been programming in R for about 4 months via the Coursera Data Science curriculum, but I have NEVER been successful in using the unzip function.

I've looked at the forums for hours for potential solutions, syntax problems, undefined arguments, etc., but to no avail.  I eventually unzip the contents manually and proceed with the assignment, but I am tired of not knowing why it is not working.

Here are a few examples of the error:

`fileName <- "StormData.zip"`

`unzip(fileName, exdir = mainDir,subDir)`

> Warning message: In unzip(fileName, exdir = mainDir, subDir) :   error
>   1 in extracting from zip file

`unzip(fileName)`

> Warning message: In unzip(fileName) : error 1 in extracting from zip
>   file

`unzip(fileName, "stormdata.csv")`

> Warning message: In unzip(fileName, "stormdata.csv") : error 1 in
>   extracting from zip file

`unzip(fileName, "stormdata.csv", list = TRUE)`

> Error in unzip(fileName, "stormdata.csv", list = TRUE) :    zip file
>   'StormData.zip' cannot be opened

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the zip file from?

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: file is download from [link](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2FStormData.csv.bz2)

Comment: I have no probems downloading and manually extracting the CSV file.  I have full administrative privileges on my computer.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error.

I changed the path --

from :

```
uzp <- "C:\\Users\\Sharvari\\Downloads\\rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata"
```

to

```
uzp <- "C:\\Users\\Sharvari\\Downloads\\rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip"
```

and it works fine!

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Sharvari\\Downloads")

uzp <- "C:\\Users\\Sharvari\\Downloads\\rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip"

unzip(uzp, exdir = "C:\\Users\\Sharvari\\Desktop\\specdata")
```

Comment: With RStudio on Windows you can also use "/" instead of "\\".

Answer (score 5):

I too was getting that error 1 message when trying to unzipping a zip file. Glitch in my case was the conflict between working directory and zip file path.

My case was:

- My working directory was like "C:/Users/SCOTT/Desktop/Training"
- While my zip file was located in "C:/Users/SCOTT/Desktop/Training/house_consumption_data"

When I was trying to execute this:

```
     unzip("house_data.zip")
```

Possibly your file is in a different folder.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem trying to download and unzip the same file, for the same course. And I have had problems with unzip in the past and was determined to solve it this time too.

Eventually the extension of the file turned out to be csv.bz2. And than this [Extract bz2 file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948777/extract-bz2-file-in-r) post solved my problem. 
After downloading the file I was able to read it directly with

```
stormdata <- read.csv("stormdata.zip")
```

without using unzip.

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to appear whenever openXLS is unable to open the specified file.
It could be a wrong name, wrong directory or the file might be encrypted or password protected

Answer (score 0):

change your zip file format this error will appear while the zip format problems occur, look at your zip file it should be "rar" change it to "zip". the function works only for "zip" format files.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Make sure that, you specify the correct name of the file(get it from the properties of .zip file) in the following code.

file = read.table(unzip("file_name.csv.zip"), sep = ",", header = TRUE)

In my case, Was just mentioning file_name.zip and R was throwing the error.

Also, there are two functions for unzipping files in R

1) **unz** - to extract single element from zip file/s
2) **unzip** - to extract all the present elements from the .zip file

I usually prefer **unzip**. 
If you will use **unz** in the above code, R will throw error again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error using install_course_zip' with a zip file. I followed all the instructions for the command faithfully but kept getting errors relating to the 'exdir'. I moved the zip file to various directories without success.

I finally used `getwd()` to get the working directory and then placed the zip file in that directory. I then was able to use the zip file name without having to use any folder structure and this worked. I still have no idea why R would not accept a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had list of files to be unzipped and processed; I was facing same error
"error 1 in extracting from zip file"

used full directory and set working directory code worked

```
files <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\Tejas naik\\Documents\\land", pattern=".zip$")

out_dir<- "C:\\Users\\Tejas naik\\Documents\\input"

setwd("C:\\Users\\Tejas naik\\Documents\\land")

for (i in files) {
  #nzip(paste(out_dir,i), exdir=out_dir)
  unzip(i,exdir=out_dir)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was happening bit differently in my case . As there was no zip file ,the issue was file was open in excel so this error was poping up .

Answer (score 0):

It's crucial to give the full name (including the path) of the zip-file to the `unzip` function.

So instead of file.zip, it should be C:\user\name\file.zip.

In case you're using the `list.files` function, one should set the `full.names` option to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error is fixed after I add \ backslash character to the filepath.
Example:
from

```
unzip("abc\aaa.zip")
```

to

```
unzip("abc\\aaa.zip")
```