# Downloading and unzipping GitHub zipped files directly in R

Tags: r, github, unzip

I am trying to download and unzip a folder of files from GitHub into R. I can manually download the file at https://github.com/dylangomes/SO/blob/main/Shape.zip and then extract all files in working directory, but I'd like to work directly from R.

```
utils::unzip("https://github.com/dylangomes/SO/blob/main/Shape.zip")

# Warning message:
# In utils::unzip("https://github.com/dylangomes/SO/blob/main/Shape.zip",  :
#  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

It says it is a warning message, although nothing has been downloaded or unzipped into my wd.

I *can* download the file to my machine:

```
utils::download.file("https://github.com/dylangomes/SO/blob/main/Shape.zip")
```

But I get the same message with the `unzip` function:

```
utils::unzip("Shape.zip")
```

And the downloaded file cannot manually be extracted. Here, I get the error that the compressed folder is empty. The `unzip` line works on the manually downloaded .zip file, which tells me something is wrong with the `download.file` line.

So if I add raw=TRUE to the end (which can make a difference in downloading data from GitHub):

```
utils::download.file("https://github.com/dylangomes/SO/blob/main/Shape.zip?raw=TRUE","Shape.zip")
utils::unzip("Shape.zip")
```

I get a different warning with, similarly, nothing being executed:

```
Warning message:
In utils::unzip("Shape.zip") : internal error in 'unz' code
```

I have tried most of the answers at [Using R to download zipped data file, extract, and import data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3053833/9096420), but they appear to be for single files that are zipped and aren't helping here. I've tried the answers at [r function unzip error 1 in extracting from zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37221184/9096420), which mentions the same warning message I am getting, but none of the solutions work in this case.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
download.file(
  "https://github.com/dylangomes/SO/blob/main/Shape.zip?raw=TRUE",
  "Shape.zip",
  mode = "wb"
)
```

Without the query string `?raw=TRUE` you are downloading the webpage and not the file.

(For Windows) R will use `mode = "wb"` by default when it detects from the end of the URL that certain file formats, including `.zip`, are being downloaded. However, the URL finishing with a query string instead of a file format means the check fails so you need to set the mode explicitly.