# R: Download Compressed File from Github ".tsv.gz" on a Mac

Tags: r, github, download, gzip, compressed-files

I have been unable to download a compressed ".tsv.gz" file from GitHub using R at the following URL on a Mac.

https://github.com/hadley/mastering-shiny/blob/main/neiss/injuries.tsv.gz

This should be a routine command, but download.file() and nothing at the following URL worked.

[Downloading and unzipping GitHub zipped files directly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73793602/downloading-and-unzipping-github-zipped-files-directly-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changing the URL to:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/mastering-shiny/main/neiss/injuries.tsv.gz

was sufficient. Weirdly, adding "?raw=TRUE" to the URL, https://github.com/hadley/mastering-shiny/blob/main/neiss/injuries.tsv.gz, which also leads to the "raw" version of the file, does not work so more color on this would be appreciated.