# How to read .json files from user-uploaded zip folder in Shiny App without unzipping to local directory?

Tags: r, shiny

Not sure if its the recent update to 4.3.2, but my shiny app is no longer able to read a user uploaded zip file. It works fine if I've already unzipped the file in the local directory, but without it I get an error: `No such file or directory`. Being that I want the app to run entirely on user-uploaded data (this app is for non-R people), this is a problem.
Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fileInput("site",
            "Upload",
            accept = "zip",
            placeholder = "upload zip"),
  tableOutput("check")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
  files <- reactive({
    d <- req(input$site)
    u <- unzip(d$datapath, list = T)
    data <- purrr::map(u$Name, jsonlite::read_json)
    data
  })

  output$check <- renderTable(files())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6051
Warning in open.connection(con, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'data/site1/visit5/rep3.csv': No such file or directory
Warning: Error in map: i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `open.connection()`:
! cannot open the connection
```

I have already looked at the question [Read csv from zip into shiny app without relying on local directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892466/read-csv-from-zip-into-shiny-app-without-relying-on-local-directories) and it doesn't address my issue. Is anyone else having the same issue? Is there a better package to use to unzip files for shiny perhaps?

Comment: After you define `d` and `u`, then use `data <- read.csv(unz(d$datapath, u$Name))` for a single file. If you're accepting multiple files then `purrr::map(u$Name, ~ read.csv(unz(d$datapath, .x)))`. (Note that I don't know how well `renderTable` will deal with a list of files ... it should work for one, I haven't tested it with multiple frames in `files()`.) If that doesn't work, please [edit] your question to update based on your changes, then @-ping me and we'll work through any issues. Hope it works!

Comment: Hmmm, tried that and I'm getting `invalid description argument.` Do I still use `u <- unzip(d$datapath, list=TRUE)`?

Comment: Yes. I just tested it with your code above and it works without error. Are you certain that the `zip` file doesn't include files you don't want to import? Perhaps add a `browser()` before your `data <- ...` line, and take a look at `u` to make sure that it doesn't have something else, such as files you don't want, or directories you cannot process.

Comment: For your change, `jsonlite::parse_json(unz(d$datapath, u$Name))` (or the `purrr::map` equivalent) should work. Note the use of `parse_json`, since `read_json` _requires_ a local filename; `parse_json` does not.

Comment: Your updated `map` is wrong too. This is a repeat from your first version: `jsonlite::read_json` requires a local file, though unlike `read.csv` it does not work with a _connection object_; instead, use `purrr::map(u$Name, ~ jsonlite::parse_json(unz(d$datapath, .x)))` or such.

Comment: YAASSS, you did it! That worked! I can't thank you enough, I spent 4 hours on this this morning. Didn't realize `read_json` requires a local file name, that was the problem. I could kiss you! THANK YOU!

Comment: Frankly, I didn't "know" a priori that it required an actual file, but two things: (1) I use `parse_json` mostly, so I tried _that_ function and it worked; then I verified with (2) if you look at the source code for `jsonlite::read_json`, you'll see that it's just a wrapper calling `parse_json` with `file(path)`, where `file(.)` here returns a connection object. That means that it is effectively trying to use `file(unz(..))`, and that nesting connection-object-stuff does not work for most/all R connection-using functions. Happy to help!