# read zip file with readtext package in R (error)

Tags: r

Using readtext package in R I got an error

```
setwd("MYDIR")

library(readtext)

zip_data = readtext("myfile.zip", text_field = "mytext_field")
```

I got this error : Error in sort_fields(result, path, text_field) : There is no field called "mytext_field" in file ~~~~(dir)

I directly checked the csv file in the zip file, there is

"mytext_field" in the csv file

what should i do?

I googled but have no luck

Answer (score 0):

You must specify .csv in your text_field

```
zip_data = readtext("myfile.zip", text_field = "mytext_field.csv")
```

Comment: Then I would try an other strategy as already explained here ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460938/r-reading-in-a-zip-data-file-without-unzipping-it