# How to read a zipped folder from my desktop in R

Tags: r, zip

I have a zipped file named "mygeodata.zip" in my desktop. This file contains two excel sheets of form xlsx, named "NOMES.xlsx" and "POLIGONAIS.xlsx"

I was wondering how I could read this zipped folder in R from my desktop.

Comment: Have a look at `?unzip`. Maybe also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460938/r-reading-in-a-zip-data-file-without-unzipping-it/12950811

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the zipped files in a folder with `unzip`. Use `list.files` to read the two files individually.

```
library(readxl)

unzip("mygeodata.zip", exdir = 'temp')
files <- list.files('temp', pattern = 'xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)

file1 <- read_excel(files[1])
file2 <- read_excel(files[2])
```

Or use `lapply` to read them in a list.

```
list_data <- lapply(file1, read_excel)
```