# How to read zip files into a list without needing an unzipped folder in the directory

Tags: r, tidyverse

Trying to read some .json files out of a zip file in R but I'm having trouble.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

data <- unzip("data.zip", list=T) %>%
  filter(!Length=="O")

files <- data$Name
jsons <- map(files, read_json)

Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'data/data/visit/site.json': No such file or directory
```

It works when I have an unzipped copy of the folder in my directory, i.e., I have both `data.zip` and `data` in my directory. Is there a way to make it work straight from the unzipped folder without needing to have an unzipped copy of the folder as well?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe this solves your problem [R Reading in a zip data file without unzipping it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46238670/9462095)