# Error message: 'exdir' does not exist when using prism package

Tags: r, prism, unzip

I am replicating the R code for a published paper about climate change that uses [prism package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prism/vignettes/prism.html) to access and visualize data from the Oregon State PRISM project.

This code stopped running with a error message of:

```
utils::unzip(outFile, exdir = ofolder) : 'exdir' does not exist
```

However, there is no unzipping in the code, except the one already defined in the prism package. This code uses two functions in the prism package: 1) get_prism_dailys, and 2) prism_set_dl_dir.

I have already read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226150/r-exdir-does-not-exist-error) about error of "exdir does not exist". But this code from the published paper does not have an unzipping command.

Can someone help me with this? Code:

```
  lapply(c("tmin","tmax"), function(var){

    print(var)

    # Set directory to write daily files
    prism_set_dl_dir(paste0(dir$prism,"/daily/",var))

    # Download files
    get_prism_dailys(type = var, minDate = "1981-01-01", maxDate = "2020-12-31", keepZip=FALSE)
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `dir$prism` is set to for you. When I modified that to be a folder that exists on my computer, the code you provided ran successfully.