# extracting Australia BOM weather data programmatically with R

Tags: r, weather, data-extraction

Here http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/data/ I can enter a substation number, say 009572; choose the variable (say Temperature) and its type (say Maximum). Clicking "get data" brings me to a page with a link "All years of data". Click it, and you got a zip file. I am aware of [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data), but here I don't have a direct link to a zip file. Can something be done to automate weather data extraction from the Australian Bureau Of Meteorology website with R?

Comment: It will be worth reading http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1309587

Comment: Look at the different parameters that get passed to the ultimate URL for the zip file (http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/weatherData/av?p_display_type=dailyZippedDataFile&p_stn_num=009572&p_c=-18462391&p_nccObsCode=123&p_startYear=1985) and see if you can compare that with the values that are passed by the HTML form. If there are pretty straightforward matches, maybe you can just `paste` together the URL for use with R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code that I have done to download instantly and it also resolves your p_c problem. You can improve the function if you want and post.

```
#daily code = 136
#monthy code = 139

bomdata<- function(station,code){
for(i in 1: length(station)){
p.url<-paste("http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/weatherData/av?p_stn_num=",station[i],"&p_display_type=availableYears&p_nccObsCode=",code,sep ="")
download.file(p.url,"test.txt")
filelist <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")
foo<- file(filelist,"r")
text<- suppressWarnings(readLines(foo))
close(foo)
l<- regexpr(":",text[1])
m<- unlist(gregexpr(",", text[1], perl = TRUE))
pc<- substr(text[1],l[[1]]+1,l[[1]]+(m[2]-(l[[1]]+1)))
url<-paste("http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/weatherData/av?p_display_type=dailyZippedDataFile&p_stn_num=",station[i],"&p_c=",pc,"&p_nccObsCode=",code,"&p_startYear=2013", sep ="")
suppressWarnings(download.file(url,paste(station[i],".zip",sep= ""), mode = "wb"))
unlink("test.txt")
 }
}
```

Example

```
bomdata(073137,136)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! I will check it out and accept your answer. An alternative solution to the p_c problem we discovered was via RCurl. We've been working on a package that makes use of that solution but your proposal may be even better. We also had to suppress warnings.

Comment: Cool!! keep posted. I haven't added any comments to function. What I did is to extract the p_c value for each station by saving it in text file, then adding the p_c value in final downloading link and saving as zip file..

Comment: Yes, the problem's solved. Well done. I'll see what parts of the two solutions may constitute the one best for use in the package.

Comment: I am really out of my depth wrt the intricacies of this code but am interested in the data it can access.  What I am finding is that it only accesses rainfall data.  How do I modify the code to get temperatures (min & max) as well?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and this S.O. question was one of the first pages to come up. After further searching I found the R package Bomrang (https://github.com/ropensci/bomrang) that:

> Provides functions to interface with Australian Government Bureau of
>   Meteorology (BOM) data, fetching data and returning a tidy data frame
>   of précis forecasts, current weather data from stations, ag
>   information bulletins, historical weather data and downloading and
>   importing radar or satellite imagery.

Bomrang is apart of rOpenSci and is actively developed. It has a good set of functions:

> Several functions are provided by bomrang to retrieve Australian
>   Bureau of Meteorology (BOM) data. A family of functions retrieve
>   weather data and return tidy data frames;
>
> ```
> get_precis_forecast(), which retrieves the précis (short) forecast;
> get_current_weather(), which fetches the current weather for a given station;
> get_ag_bulletin(), which retrieves the agriculture bulletin;
> get_weather_bulletin(), which retrieves the BOM 0900 or 1500 bulletins;
> get_coastal_forecast(), which returns coastal waters forecasts; and
> get_historical(), which retrieves historical daily observations for a given station.
> ```
>
> A second group of functions retrieve information pertaining to
>   satellite and radar imagery,
>
> ```
> get_available_imagery();
> the satellite imagery itself, get_satellite_imagery();
> get_available_radar(); and
> the radar imagery itself, get_radar_imagery().
> ```

The function `get_historical()` seems to do what OP is needing. For example, to get the historical daily rainfall from a weather station in Sydney is as easy as:

```
> rain_066062 <- bomrang::get_historical(stationid = 066062,
+                         type = 'rain',
+                         meta = T)
> head(rain_066062)
$`meta`
# A tibble: 1 x 10
   site name                        lat   lon start      end        years percent AWS   ncc_obs_code
  <int> <chr>                     <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl>   <int> <chr> <chr>       
1 66062 SYDNEY (OBSERVATORY HILL) -33.9  151. 1858-07-01 2018-11-01  160.     100 Y     136         

$historical_data
      Product_code Station_number Year Month Day Rainfall Period Quality
1       IDCJAC0009          66062 1858     1   1       NA     NA        
2       IDCJAC0009          66062 1858     1   2       NA     NA        
3       IDCJAC0009          66062 1858     1   3       NA     NA        
4       IDCJAC0009          66062 1858     1   4       NA     NA        
5       IDCJAC0009          66062 1858     1   5       NA     NA      
<<SNIP>>
```

Another nice feature is if you have the longitude and latitude of a place of interest, get_historical() will find the nearest weather station to that location.

To install from CRAN:

```
install.packages("bomrang")
```

Or install the development version from Github:

```
if (!require("remotes")) {
  install.packages("remotes", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  library("remotes")
}

install_github("ropensci/bomrang", build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it is a code sequence used by metvurst package. [metvurst](http://tim-salabim.github.io/metvurst/)

```
## SET URL FOR DATA DOWNLOAD
url <- "http://www.bom.gov.au/ntc/IDO70004/IDO70004_"

## YEARS TO BE DOWNLOADED
yr <- 1993:2012

## READ DATA FOR ALL YEARS FROM URL INTO LIST
fijilst <- lapply(seq(yr), function(i) {
read.csv(paste(url, yr[i], ".csv", sep = ""), na.strings = c(-9999, 999))
})
```

Comment: Yes, I still need something like this for an individual Australian weather station. The code you supplied works with ID numbers / file names listed here http://www.bom.gov.au/oceanography/projects/spslcmp/data/data.shtml, which is not quite Australia.

Answer (score 0):

While I still can't see how to do this with download.file(), the following almost does the job provided Chrome's "Ask where to save each file before downloading" is unticked.

```
system(paste('"C:/Documents and Settings/UserName/Local Settings/Application Data/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"',
         '-url http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/weatherData/av?p_display_type=dailyZippedDataFile&p_stn_num=009572&p_c=-18465084&p_nccObsCode=136'), wait = FALSE)
```

Then I could use paste0() and loop through various station numbers if I knew what p_c=-18465084  means and how it changes from station to station.