# Using R to download zipped data file, extract, and import .csv

Tags: r, csv, zip, download

I am trying to download and extract a .csv file from a webpage using **R**.

This question is a duplicate of [Using R to download zipped data file, extract, and import data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data).

I cannot get the solution to work, but it may be due to the web address i am using.

I am trying to download the .csv files from http://data.worldbank.org/country/united-kingdom (under the **download data** drop down)

Using @Dirk's solution from the link above, i tried

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/country/gbr?downloadformat=csv",temp)
con <- unz(temp, "gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv")
dat <- read.table(con, header=T, skip=2)
unlink(temp)
```

I got the extended link by looking at the page source code, which I expect is causing the problems, although it works if i paste it into the address bar.

The file downloads with the correct Gb

```
download.file("http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/country/gbr?downloadformat=csv",temp)
# trying URL 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/country/gbr?downloadformat=csv'
# Content type 'application/zip' length 332358 bytes (324 Kb)
# opened URL
# downloaded 324 Kb

# also tried unzip but get this warning
con <- unzip(temp, "gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv")
# Warning message:
# In unzip(temp, "gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv") :
# requested file not found in the zip file
```

But these are the file names when i manually download them.

I'd appreciate some help with where i am going wrong , thanks

I am using Windows 8, R version 3.1.0

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to get your data to download and uncompress, you need to set `mode="wb"`

```
download.file("...",temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp, "gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv")
dd <- read.table("gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv", sep=",",skip=2, header=T)
```

It looks like the default is "w" which assumes a text files. If it was a plain csv file this would be fine. But since it's compressed, it's a binary file, hence the "wb". Without the "wb" part, you can't open the zip at all.

Comment: I've been struggling with the exact same question for hours, thanks for your answer and the clear-cut explanation... Worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

It's almost everything ok. In this case you only need to specify that it's a comma separated file, eg using `sep=","` in `read.table`:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/country/gbr?downloadformat=csv", 
              temp)
con <- unz(temp, "gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv")
dat <- read.table(con, header=T, skip=2, sep=",")
unlink(temp)
```

With this little change i can import your csv smoothly.

HTH, Luca

Comment: Thanks Luca, i do need the separator. However, it is failing at the `unz` or `unzip` stage. At `read.table` it still cannot locate the file. Did this above codes work for you?

Comment: @MrFlick Debian Gnu/Linux

Comment: @LucaBraglia OK. I think Windows has a different default or the file was crossing OS boundaries and Windows was getting goofed up trying to translate line endings.

Answer (score 5):

The Word Bank Developmet Indictors can be obtained using the [WDI package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=WDI).  For example,

```
library(WDI)
inds <- WDIsearch(field = "indicator")[, 1]
GB <- WDI("GB", indicator = inds)
```

See [WDIsearch](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/wdi/docs/WDIsearch) and [WDI](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/wdi/docs/WDI) functions and the [rerference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/package=WDI) for more info.