# R: Download file from internet

Tags: r

I am having problem downloading a csv file from internet.

I tried the following code, but I wasn't able to make it work.

```
myurl <- "http://unstats.un.org/unsd/mdg/Handlers/ExportHandler.ashx?Type=Csv&Series=761"
download.file(myurl, destfile="./test.csv",method="curl")
```

Instead I received the following output.

> ```
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100 16313  100 16313    0     0  11961      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 11959100 16313  100 16313    0     0  11960      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 11959
> ```

When I manually download, a file like this is generated "MDG_Export_20150821_224828123.csv". 
The server generates a new file name (MDG_Export + date + time).

Is there anyway I can download this from my R program because the manual download is not an option in my project?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried just reading it with `read.csv(url(myurl), ....)`? Do you really want to save it or just use it in R?

Comment: The file is a `zip` file , so you need to download it, `unzip` it then read in to R. There is also some noise at the bottom of the text file - `fread` from `data.table` package is good for making helpful assumptions. This seems to work `download.file(myurl, temp <- tempfile()) ;
lst <- unzip(temp, list=TRUE)   ;  dat <- data.table::fread(unzip(temp, lst$Name), header=TRUE)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899525/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-csv and for additional links

Comment: There is an `unz` file connection function.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. As you mentioned there is noise at the bottom. I had to remove it before saving the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myurl <- "http://unstats.un.org/unsd/mdg/Handlers/ExportHandler.ashx?Type=Csv&Series=761&filename=MDG_Export_20150821_224828123.zip"
myzip <- unz(myurl, filename='MDG_Export_20150821_224828123.zip')
download.file(myurl, destfile="./test.zip",method="curl")
```

You will then need to expand the file with `unzip`