# How read a large dataset from .rar extension in R?

Tags: r, csv, rar, ff

I have a data set that weighs 4GB compressed and more than 20GB uncompressed.

The file can be downloaded [here](http://www.conentotecnologia.com/files_2358290812349028359/song_log.rar).

I have tried several ways to load it and It have not been possible. There are similar questions in stackoverflow ([question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647779/r-download-and-unzip-file-to-store-in-data-frame), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data))

I tried what they suggest and I have the same problems that the questioner.

I have tried to change manually the extension of the file from `.rar` to `.gz` and read it from two ways and only a few rows but it doesn't work:

## Code:

```
#First attemp
data <- read.table(gzfile("./data_in/song_log.gz"),header = F,sep=",",nrow=10)
data <- read.csv(gzfile("./data_in/song_log.gz"),header = F,sep=",",nrow=10)
data <- read.csv2(gzfile("./data_in/song_log.gz"),header = F,sep=",",nrow=10)


#Triying with "ff" package

library("ff")
data <- ff::read.csv.ffdf(gzfile("./data_in/song_log.gz"),header = F,sep=",",nrow=10)
Error in read.table.ffdf(FUN = "read.csv", ...) : 
  only ffdf objects can be used for appending (and skipping the first.row chunk)
```

Any suggestion for this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
devtools::install_github("jimhester/archive") # mind the install guidelines at https://github.com/jimhester/archive/blob/master/configure#L64-L72
library(archive)

con <- archive_read("~/Data/song_log.rar")

readLines(con, 3)
## [1] "hora;userId;songId;generoId;deviceId;trendingSong" "18-12-2016 00:00:25;27103;231990117;23;1_27103;0" 
## [3] "18-12-2016 00:02:00;74637;241781021;24;1_74637;0"
```

You can use anything that can take in an R `connection` object.

I'm not abt to read in 20GB for the example but those lines worked and I'd suggest using Apache Drill with the `sergeant` package and converting this CSV to parquet.

Comment: I don't know what happen but I try to execute this code and inmediately I have the bomb that says "R Session Aborted" :-(