# Download and Read Zip CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv, zip, kaggle

I am trying to download and read a zipped csv file from Kaggle within an R script. After researching other posts including [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899525/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-csv) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) I have tried:

```
# Read data with temp file
url <- "https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/download/store.csv.zip"
tmp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, tmp, mode = "wb")
con <- unz(tmp, "store.csv.zip")
store <- read.table(con, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
unlink(tmp)
```

the read.table command throws an error:

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

I have also tried:

```
# Download file, unzip, and read
url <- "https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/download/store.csv.zip"
download.file(url, destfile = "./SourceData/store.csv.zip", mode = "wb")
unzip("./SourceData/store.csv.zip")
```

Unzip throws the error:

```
error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Bypassing the unzip command and reading directly from the zip file

```
store <- read_csv("SourceData/store.csv.zip")
```

Throws the error:

```
zip file ... SourceData/store.csv.zip cannot be opened
```

I prefer to use the temp file, but at this point I'll use either approach if I can make it work.

Comment: Sorry, the title should of course be "file"

Comment: Might the error be the result of the fact that you have to log in on the website?

Comment: The error ''Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection" may indicate the lack of file where the function expect it.

Comment: Can you prove that the file is indeed in the folder R reads from?

Comment: 1. The site does require a log-in.2. In the temp file example, there is a file created in the Temp directory that corresponds to the error message "cannot open zip file 'C:\Users\TBOOM_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSohNid\file185438603dd7'". In the Download file example, a zip file is created in the directory. Also, if I try to open the downloaded zip file in Windows 10 I "Windows cannot open the compressed folder...the compressed (zip) folder is invalid."