# how to download and unzip a zip file in R?

Tags: r, zip, unzip

I am a totally new user of R, now I need to download and unzip http://gdac.broadinstitute.org/runs/code/firehose_get_latest.zip in my R, I have tried the code:

```
temp <- tempfile()
> download.file("http://gdac.broadinstitute.org/runs/code/firehose_get_latest.zip",temp)
```

however, when I tried the following code:

```
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "firehose_get_latest"))
```

it showed that

> ```
> Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In open.connection(file, "rt") :
>   cannot locate file 'firehose_get_latest' in zip file '/tmp/RtmpotKFGQ/file11ff4f04fe46'
> ```

So what should I do to then?
ANY HELP ARE APPRECIATED!

Comment: please google, this is surely a duplicate

Comment: Assuming that `temp` contains the full path to your file, did you try `data <- read.table(unz(temp, "firehose_get_latest.zip"))`?

Comment: You don't need a temp file for `unz()`.  The first argument is the zip file name.  Then the `filename` argument in `unz()` needs to be the exact file name from within the zip file that you want to read (i.e. with extension if it has one).  You probably need to add `.csv` or `.txt` or whatever extension is used for that file.  It's all documented in `help(unz)`

Comment: Also if you are on Windows you need `mode="wb"`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899525/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-csv

Comment: Also, you can see what's in the zip (all the file names) without unzipping it with `unzip("firehose_get_latest.zip", list = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you very much!! My problem is that I did not add the pathway to the file name ! Really appreciate for your kind help!~