# How can I install the Bioconductor package "liftOver" in a conda environment?

Tags: r, conda, bioconductor

I'm trying to install the Bioconductor package [`liftOver`](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/html/liftOver.html) using conda. I'm creating a conda environment using a `.yml` file like this:
`conda env create -f coo_environment.yml`

When I do this, I get:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - bioconductor-liftover
```

The relevant contents of `coo_environment.yml` are shown below

```
name: coo

channels:
        - conda-forge
        - bioconda
dependencies:
        # R
        - bioconductor-exomeCopy
        - bioconductor-rtracklayer
        - bioconductor-liftOver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bioconductor has a `liftOver` *Workflow*, but Bioconda does not package any of [the Bioconductor Workflows](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/workflows/). Such workflows are not supposed to introduce new functionality, but instead demonstrate how to work with a set of tools in the ecosystem. They can include additional data for convenient demonstrations.

In this case, the `liftOver` reimplementation is provided *as part of* the `rtracklayer` package, so the `bioconductor-rtracklayer` is sufficient to provide that functionality.

You can access the function in R with

```r
rtracklayer::liftOver
```

The `liftOver` workflow also includes some example `.chain` files. UCSC is the canonical source for these and can be found in [the Downloads section of the website](http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/downloads.html). In practice at our research group, reference files like this are kept in a centralized location, so I would load from that.

If you want to download the hg38 to hg19 file programmatically, I am unaware of any dedicated functionality for this, but other answers cover downloading and unzipping files in R (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899525/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-csv)).

Comment: I was using the line `hg38_path = system.file(package="liftOver", "extdata", "hg38ToHg19.over.chain")` in my code. How can I modify it to make it work if I'm not actually loading the `liftOver` package?

Answer (score 0):

`pyliftover` is python implementation of UCSC `liftOver` genome coordinate conversion. So change the last line in your `yml` to `pyliftover`. Alternatively, you can also use `ucsc-liftover`.

Comment: Users should avoid installing Python and R in the same environment as much as possible - it complicates solves. So, I'd strongly recommend against an R user resorting to `pyliftover`. The UCSC binary is fine, but still this misses the intent of the question, which is to specifically use the Bioconductor implementation.