# Error: unexpected string constant in file path in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run this command in R in order to run a function:

```
 xlsxToR <- function("C:\\Users\\Nabila\\Dropbox\\IsolutionsProject\\ServiceRequestTickets.zip", keep_sheets = "TicketDetails", header = FALSE)
```

However, I tend to get this error when I run it:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "xlsxToR <- function("C:\\Users\\Nabila\\Dropbox\\IsolutionsProject\\ServiceRequestTickets.zip""
```

I have tried looking for a mistake in my file path. Tried using forward slashes but to no avail. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but this SO question has information on opening zip files in R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data

Comment: try giving the string constant a name, like `function(file = "C:\\Users\\Nabila\\Dropbox\\IsolutionsProject\\ServiceRequestTickets.zip", ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functions in R**

When you are using `function` in R you are defining a function (You can use `?function` to see the documentation). Inside the parentheses after `function` you set the arguments of the function. You can also set default values for those arguments using `=`. After that the body of the function should follow, i.e. an R expression containing the code of the function.

**Your case**

This line of code does not run a function. It defines a function with name `xlsxToR`. The first thing in the parenthesis is a string, not an argument name, which causes the error. Also your function is just a definition of some argumnents without a body, which probably is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, the code for the function follows after this line, but I did not copy it here.

Comment: No problem. It was unclear from your question, because you said "run" a function and not showing the body of the function.