# Using R to download and read zipped xml file

Tags: xml, r, zip

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3053883/891259) answer by Dirk Eddelbuettel I am trying to read an `xml` file from a `zip` archive for further processing. Apart from URL and filenames the only change to the code referenced is that I changed `read.table` to `xmlInternalTreeParse`.

```
library(XML)
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/NavTree_prod/everybody/BulkDownloadListing?sort=1&downfile=data%2Fnrg_105a.sdmx.zip",temp)
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(unz(temp, "nrg_105a.dsd.xml"))
fileunlink(temp)
closeAllConnections()
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument
```

`traceback()`shows that this is a function call from within the parser. So temp seems to be an inappropriate reference in this context. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `xmlInternalTreeParse` doesn't appear to work the same way as `read.table`. Whereas `read.table` can take a connection object, `xmlInternalTreeParse` require a file name (as a character) according to the documentation.

Comment: Hmm, I never really understood what a connection is. So I probably need to convert the connection to a character vector with `readLines` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Make a temporary file (tf) and a temporary folder (tdir)
tf <- tempfile(tmpdir = tdir <- tempdir())

## Download the zip file 
download.file("http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/NavTree_prod/everybody/BulkDownloadListing?sort=1&downfile=data%2Fnrg_105a.sdmx.zip", tf)

## Unzip it in the temp folder
xml_files <- unzip(tf, exdir = tdir)

## Parse the first file
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(xml_files[1])

## Delete temporary files
unlink(tdir, T, T)
```

Comment: Great this works. On closer inspection I found that both codes do essentially the same but yours uses `unzip`instead of `unz`. Using the former makes the original script run as well.

Comment: The problem is that `xmlInternalTreeParse` needs a filename, not a connection (what `unz` returns). Yes you are right, but it saves the extracted xml in your current directory.