# R extracting a single XML file from archive

Tags: xml, r

I have a medium sized archive (zipped roughly 140Mb). I need to access single xml-files only, as there are roughly 50.000 xml-files, I want to use the `unz`-function to extract a single xml-file instead of unzipping the whole folder.

Using the approach proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data), my code looks like this:

```
library(XML)
f.path <- "path to zip-archive/"
# establish a connection to the file
dat <- unz(paste0(f.path, "BKK-Download.zip"), filename = "lists/www_s100_bh8285_1_3.xml")
# trying to parse the xml code
xml.content <- xmlParse(dat)

# which returns
# Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument
```

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005565/using-r-to-download-and-read-zipped-xml-file), but I want to extract only a single file instead of unzipping the 50k files.

Any ideas of how to fix this?
Any help is much appreciated!

**Appendix:** 
You can find the dataset [here (direct link)](http://www.bundesbank.de/cae/servlet/StatisticDownload?its_fileFormat=Archive&mode=its) (source: [Deutsche Bundesbank (website)](http://www.bundesbank.de/Redaktion/EN/Standardartikel/Statistics/additional_download_options.html))

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, it is indeed paste0 in my script.

Comment: True, but the error comes up when I call `xmlParse`, the connection `dat` looks fine! (i.e., tested with a .csv file and read.data. Works fine, but not xml.)

Comment: The path seperator in this case is in `f.path`, it ends with a "/"....

Comment: You may need to save as a `gzip` and use `gzcon` as `help(xmlParse)` doesn't mention any other connections can be used in its `file` argument

Comment: What about `xmlParse(readLines(con = dat))`?

Comment: @lukeA, good idea, however, it returns: `Error in readLines(con = dat) : cannot open the connection 
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(con = dat) :
  cannot open zip file ` on my machine!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error, works fine here.

Comment: @lukeA. If I try to replicate the error with another .zip archive it works fine! 
However, with the "Bundesbank" zip archive, it doesn't work, returning the error as mentioned before. Did you try to reproduce the error with another zip or with the "Bundesbank"-file?

Comment: @David with "Bundesbank"

Comment: @lukA, ok. Thank you for your help!
I "rezipped" the files again and now everything works fine with the Bundesbank archive. As I don't have admin rights on the machine, I assume it has to do something with rights...
Again, thanks for the effort! :)