# download large zipped csv over https, unzip, and load

Tags: r

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) to download a zipped file over https, extract the csv file (14GB), and load the data into a dataframe. I created a small example (<1MB).

```
library(data.table)
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/h130oe03krthcl0/example.csv.zip",
              temp, method="curl")
data <- fread(unz(temp, "example.csv"))
unlink(temp)
```

Is my mistake obvious?

Comment: `R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)`; `Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)`

Comment: As far as I know, `fread()` does not currently support the use of `unz()`.  See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/717).  You will probably need to unzip the file unless there has been a solution posted in that thread

Comment: You could try `unzip(temp, file = "example.csv"); fread("example.csv")`

Comment: thanks. `unzip()` is not working for me. i've come across this error in other variants of what i've tried today. i can't pinpoint the reason.

Comment: This might be irrelevant but the comment in this suggested edit of the question points out something interesting about the url you are using: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9614251

Comment: @spenibus that is interesting. i tried with the modification, but i still have the problem.

Comment: You're not helping us out much here.  Are you getting an error?  What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me (`download.file` does too but I'm on 3.2.2 OS X so this is more "portable" given the updates to `download.file` since 3.1.2):

```
library(httr)

response <- GET("https://www.dropbox.com/s/h130oe03krthcl0/example.csv.zip?dl=1",
                write_disk("example.csv.zip"),
                progress())

fil <- unzip("example.csv.zip")
read.csv(fil[1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

##   v1 v2 v3
## 1  1  2  3
## 2  1  2  3
## 3  1  2  3
```

I didn't try it w/o the `?dl=1` (& I do that by wrote, not due to the edit queue suggestion).

Honestly, though, I'd probably spare the download in R and just use `curl` on the command line in an automated workflow for files the size you've indicated (and, I'd do that if the processing language was python [et al], too).

Answer (score 0):

In my of the application I was trying to download the zip file from http and just create stream for unzipping that file into a folder.

After making some google search I was able to write following code which helps me in my task

Here are few steps you have to follow

1. Install unzipper package
2. import unzipper and http into the code file

import unzipper from ‘unzipper’;

import http from ‘http’;

3. Now you have to download the zip file and create stream for this, here is the complete code

import unzipper from ‘unzipper’;

import http from ‘http’;

var self=this;

http.get(‘http://yoururl.com/file.zip’, function(res) {

```
         res.pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: ‘C:/cmsdata/’ })).on(‘close’, function() {
                   //Here you can perform any action after completion of stream unzipping
         });
```

});