# Download NSE (zipped and CSV ) data

Tags: r

```
require(curl) 
require(RCurl) 
require(downloader) 
temp <- tempfile()
sURL <- "http://www.nseindia.com/archives/equities/bhavcopy/pr/PR240915.zip"

download(sURL,dest="C:/Users/sayantan/Documents/Data",mode="wb")

con <- unzip(temp, extdir="C:/Data") 
data <- matrix(scan(con),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE) 
unlink(temp)
```

But this code is not working. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get error messages? At which line?

Comment: I unzipped your zipped file and it contained many files. You should choose one.

Comment: @nTuple - You may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) SO post.

Comment: ` library(RCurl) sURL <- "http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/block.csv" options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))) x <- getURL(sURL)
## Or 
## x <- getURL(sURL, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
out <- read.csv(textConnection(x))
head(out) `

Comment: @Stibu error is "403 access denied"

Comment: I can not reproduce that error. Downloading the file works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nser` package.

```
library(nser)
bhav("12082020")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Quantmod or Quandl to download data from NSE. 
I prefer Quandl over Quantmod, as Quandl directly downloads from NSE whereas Quantmod uses Yahoo to get data for Indian equities.

In Quandl simple use NSE's Ticker to get data
For example type
data <- Quandl("NSE/SBIN", start_date="2005-01-01", end_date="2015-12-31") to get SBI's daily data.