# Extract specific file from zip

Tags: r, zip

I would like to load up in R memory the data from text files I downloaded. The zip file is the same folder of the rStudio project, and it has two sublevels, where there are three files of my interest, in `temp.zip/final/en_US`.

I went through the [zip function documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/unzip.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) brilliant post, whitout fortune.

Please find here my last attempt.

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/dsscapstone/dataset/Coursera-SwiftKey.zip", temp)
```

The `temp.zip` file has 10 subfolders.

```
 [1] "./final/de_DE/de_DE.twitter.txt" "./final/de_DE/de_DE.blogs.txt"  
 [3] "./final/de_DE/de_DE.news.txt"    "./final/ru_RU/ru_RU.blogs.txt"  
 [5] "./final/ru_RU/ru_RU.news.txt"    "./final/ru_RU/ru_RU.twitter.txt"
 [7] "./final/en_US/en_US.twitter.txt" "./final/en_US/en_US.news.txt"   
 [9] "./final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt"   "./final/fi_FI/fi_FI.news.txt"   
[11] "./final/fi_FI/fi_FI.blogs.txt"   "./final/fi_FI/fi_FI.twitter.txt"
```

Since `temp.zip` is quite big, I would like to open a connection or extract the data only from the 7th, 8th and 9th element, without unzip/load the whole `temp.zip`.

Comment: It is not clear. You have unzipped your file, then you have multiple subfolders?

Comment: That is way too big of a file to download. If you want help reading a particular file into R, include a snippet of the text file.

Comment: Yes it is confusing. I would like to load in memory only the data in the subfolders 7, 8 and 9 of the `temp.zip`. Thank you for the suggestion. A snippet is part of one of the text files?

Comment: You can try read.table(unz("temp.zip", "final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt"))