# Read specific file from tar.gz in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have a large `tar.gz` file (>2GB) from which I want to read a specific `.dat` file in R **without unzipping** the original `tar.gz` file.

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data) as follows:

```
p35_data_path <- "~/P35_fullset.tar.gz" 
file.exists(p35_data_path) #TRUE

# Try to readin foldera/class1/mydata.dat from the zip file
mydata <- read.table(unz(p35_data_path
                       , "foldera/class1/mydata.dat"))
```

When I run the above I get a `read.table` error as

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot open zip file '~/P35_fullset.tar.gz'
```

The `"~/P35_fullset.tar.gz"` file exists. And the specific file within it definitely exists `foldera/class1/mydata.dat`.

Could anyone please assist in rectifying this?

Comment: You mean "not unzipping the original `tar.gz` to ssd/spindle-based storage" since it does have to be decompressed in memory. NOTE also that `unz()` is only for `.zip` files. Not sure where you got the impression it handled `.tar.gz` from. Check out the [`archive`](https://github.com/jimhester/archive) package.

Comment: @hrbrmstr. Thanks - I basically didn't want to untar all of the contents to disk. I could untar specific files to disk but this took too long for a single file, so thought there may be a way to do it by just accessing them individually. I'll check out the `archive` package and report back with queries

Comment: This worked for me (thanks @hrbrmstr) ```p35_data_path <- "~/P35_fullset.tar.gz" 
# Try to readin foldera/class1/mydata.dat from the zip file
x <- archive::archive_read(archive = p35_data_path
                           , file = "foldera/class1/mydata.dat")
mydata <- readr::read_csv(x)```

Comment: Added an option using library(archive) which worked well for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
da < -untar(Tarfile, files = NULL, list = TRUE, exdir = ".",compressed = "gzip") # this is for listing the files under TAR

da < -as.data.table(da) # save listed files as datatable
```

Then use your own filter technique to filtes the files like I did and saved in `Name`:

```
g <- c(da$Name)`  # then list the names

untar(Tarfile, files = g, list = FALSE, exdir = "exportRQA",compressed = "gzip") # This is finally the command for extracting the specific files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `library(archive)` one can read in a particular csv file within an archive without having to UNZIP it first :

```
library(archive)
library(readr)
read_csv(archive_read("~/P35_fullset.tar.gz", file = 1), col_types = cols())
```

(adjust file=XX as appropriate)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to unpack the archive with base R's  `untar()`:

```
p35_data_path <- "~/P35_fullset.tar.gz" 
file.exists(p35_data_path) #TRUE

# Try to readin foldera/class1/mydata.dat from the .tar.gz file
untar(p35_data_path, "foldera/class1/mydata.dat")  # this extracts the file from archive
mydata <- read.table("foldera/class1/mydata.dat")  # so you can read it
```

The file is extracted inside the folder, however, you can specify where to extract it. See [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/untar.html) for more info.