# "Permission denied" to download .zip to RStudio

Tags: rstudio

Trying to download a temporary file .zip

```
download.file("http://microdatos.dane.gov.co/index.php/catalog/548/download/9392/Estructura CHC_2017.zip", destfile = "Estructura CHC_2017.zip")
```

but I'm getting this message

> Error in
>   download.file("http://microdatos.dane.gov.co/index.php/catalog/548/download/9392/Estructura
>   CHC_2017.zip",  :    cannot open destfile 'Estructura CHC_2017.zip',
>   reason 'Permission denied'

Comment: [Check this out?](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-Download-Permission-Denied-td4641568.html)

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data