# Read dataset from Kaggle

Tags: r, kaggle

I am trying to download data into R from Kaggle using the below command. The datasets I am trying to download are located [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/elo-merchant-category-recommendation/data).

```
library(httr)
dataset <- GET("https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/competitions/data/download/10445/train.csv", 
         authenticate(username, authkey, type = "basic"))
```

The variable `dataset` is of type `"application/zip"`. Can someone help me get the csv file from inside the link?(I used `http_type(train)`  Please let me know if my question is unclear

Edit: Included library name based on comments.

Comment: Where does function `GET` come from? Secondly, I get "This page isn't working" when I try the link.

Comment: The function comes from the package `httr`. It's written by Hadley Wickham. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.0/topics/GET

Comment: Always *explicitly* include any non base R library calls; in your case `library(httr)`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers: The url in the GET function doesn't work by itself. But it can help pull data based on the authentication.  The datasets are located at https://www.kaggle.com/c/elo-merchant-category-recommendation/data.   I am struggling to pull a dataset from Kaggle into R directly. If there's a more elegant way to do it, I am all eyes and ears. Neither kaggler package nor some functions I found on Kaggle worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution based on the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data). Someone posted the link in the comment but I don't see the comment any more. Thank you Good Samaritan!

```
library(httr)
dataset <- httr::GET("https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/competitions/data/download/10445/train.csv", 
                 httr::authenticate(username, authkey, type = "basic"))

temp <- tempfile()
download.file(dataset$url,temp)
data <- read.csv(unz(temp, "train.csv"))
unlink(temp)
```

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to answer and accept your own answer. So you might want to set the green checkmark next to the answer to close the question.

Comment: Stackoverflow forces people to wait for two days before accepting their own solution as an answer. I will keep tab and check the green mark in two days

Comment: If I may ask, how did you go about getting the download link from kaggle