# Load CSV dataset into R directly from Kaggle

Tags: r, httr, kaggle, read.csv, data-import

I need to load a CSV dataset directly to R from Kaggle without pre-downloading the CSV file. I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272909/read-dataset-from-kaggle) how to unzip a csv file using `GET()` function from `httr` package, but for that I need the URL of the download. On Kaggle I can see only the Download button link '.../download', without the exact address to the zipped csv file. Is there any way to get the link to the zipped csv file on Kaggle?

I also found the [kaggler package](https://github.com/mkearney/kaggler), but it seems working only for my own datasets that are under my account. While I would like to load into R datasets uploaded by other Kaggle users. Is there any way to do it in R?

Here is an [example of Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/benroshan/factors-affecting-campus-placement). I would need to load the `Placement_Data_Full_Class.csv` directly into R.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272909/read-dataset-from-kaggle

Comment: Thank you, i cannot find on Kaggle where the URL (https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/competitions/data/download/10445/train.csv) in GET() function comes from.