# Read Kaggle dataset into r without downloading at first

Tags: r, dataset, kaggle

I want to import the Kaggle dataset into Rstudio without downloading it at first. I followed this website, [Read dataset from Kaggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272909/read-dataset-from-kaggle) but it failed, I do not know how to find the username. Could you please help me fix it?

This is my dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/shawon10/web-log-dataset

```
library(httr)
dataset <- httr::GET("https://www.kaggle.com/shawon10/web-log-dataset?select=weblog.csv", 
                 httr::authenticate(username, authkey, type = "basic"))

temp <- tempfile()
download.file(dataset$url,temp)
data <- read.csv(unz(temp, "train.csv"))
unlink(temp)
```

[image]

Comment: You have to enter Kaggle `username` and `authkey`

Comment: I have tried it but it still failed. Anyway, thanks.