Download file by using R
I have this url : "https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nelgiriyewithana/most-streamed-spotify-songs-2024/download"
I want to download the dataset from the url , but I failed... knowing it should be simple but I really stuck ...
Anyway, I use httr package.
Here are my attempt(s):
First attempt :
url <- "https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nelgiriyewithana/most-streamed-spotify-songs-2024/download"

download.file(url = url,
              destfile = "spotiy_2014_data")

Second attempt :
url <- "https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nelgiriyewithana/most-streamed-spotify-songs-2024/download"

download.file(url = url,
              destfile = "spotiy_2014_data.zip")

How can I make it succeed? Need help...

Neither of your attempts is using the ‘httr’ package. (And, at any rate, that package is superseded by the ‘httr2’ package).

How does it fail, what messages are shown?

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/55272909/680068

@ZéLoff I would say the file is being downloaded, but the file can't be opened normally. Do you get what I mean...

@ZéLoff The issue is that Kaggle requires authentication to download datasets. Unfortunately the documentation does not spell out how to pass the authentication to the API but I’m assuming they support both basic and bearer token authentication. So passing headers = c(Authentication = 'Bearer ‹TOKEN›') to download.file() will probably work.

@Friede sadly, still not. Even though I have got the "username" and "key" from through the API...

@ZéLoff yes... I have used
dataset <- GET(url = url,                authenticate(                  user = username,                  password = key,                  type = "basic"                  )                )
But still not able to do that...

With httr2 and Kaggle Token saved as kaggle.json in your working directory:
library(httr2)

credentials <- jsonlite::read_json("kaggle.json")
request(paste0("https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/datasets/download/", 
               "nelgiriyewithana/most-streamed-spotify-songs-2024")) |> 
  req_auth_basic(credentials$username, credentials$key) |>
  req_perform(path = "kaggle_tmp.zip")
#> <httr2_response>
#> GET
#> https://storage.googleapis.com:443/kaggle-data-sets/5218014/8700156/bundle/archive.zip?...
#> Content-Type: application/zip
#> Body: On disk 'kaggle_tmp.zip' (508134 bytes)

readr::read_csv("kaggle_tmp.zip")
#> Rows: 4600 Columns: 29
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (5): Track, Album Name, Artist, Release Date, ISRC
#> dbl  (6): Track Score, Spotify Popularity, Apple Music Playlist Count, Deeze...
#> num (17): All Time Rank, Spotify Streams, Spotify Playlist Count, Spotify Pl...
#> lgl  (1): TIDAL Popularity
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 4,600 × 29
#>    Track  `Album Name` Artist `Release Date` ISRC  `All Time Rank` `Track Score`
#>    <chr>  <chr>        <chr>  <chr>          <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 MILLI… "Million Do… Tommy… 4/26/2024      QM24…               1          725.
#>  2 Not L… "Not Like U… Kendr… 5/4/2024       USUG…               2          546.
#>  3 i lik… "I like the… Artem… 3/19/2024      QZJ8…               3          538.
#>  4 Flowe… "Flowers - … Miley… 1/12/2023      USSM…               4          445.
#>  5 Houdi… "Houdini"    Eminem 5/31/2024      USUG…               5          423.
#>  6 Lovin… "Lovin On M… Jack … 11/10/2023     USAT…               6          410.
#>  7 Beaut… "Beautiful … Benso… 1/18/2024      USWB…               7          407.
#>  8 Gata … "Gata Only"  Floyy… 2/2/2024       QZL3…               8          376.
#>  9 Danza… "\xfd\xfd\x… MUSIC… 6/9/2024       TCJP…               9          356.
#> 10 BAND4… "BAND4BAND … Centr… 5/23/2024      USSM…              10          331.
#> # ℹ 4,590 more rows
#> # ℹ 22 more variables: `Spotify Streams` <dbl>, `Spotify Playlist Count` <dbl>,
#> #   `Spotify Playlist Reach` <dbl>, `Spotify Popularity` <dbl>,
#> #   `YouTube Views` <dbl>, `YouTube Likes` <dbl>, `TikTok Posts` <dbl>,
#> #   `TikTok Likes` <dbl>, `TikTok Views` <dbl>, `YouTube Playlist Reach` <dbl>,
#> #   `Apple Music Playlist Count` <dbl>, `AirPlay Spins` <dbl>,
#> #   `SiriusXM Spins` <dbl>, `Deezer Playlist Count` <dbl>, …

Created on 2024-06-25 with reprex v2.1.0

Hey @margusl , thank you!! Just curious... may I know why it is "https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/datasets/download/" at first? Because when I tried to browse, the webpage show "We can't find that page." ...

Because we interact with Kaggle though its API (application programming interface), just like in the duplicate question (also linked in the comments). Interface is documented here - https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/blob/main/docs/KaggleApi.md . There's also R client for Kaggle, though currently not available through  CRAN - https://koderkow.github.io/kaggler/ . You can see more examples on how to make Kaggle competition submissions etc from its source code.
