# How to unzip a file .zip in R

Tags: r

I would like to unzip a .zip file in R. After unzipping, I would like to read the file `.shp`, so I did the following:

```
library(rgdal)

temp <- tempfile() 
download.file("https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/ac61a729b3856112bcb100f4dfb2c900565fdb54/gasoduto1.zip",temp) 
con <- readOGR(unz(temp, "gasoduto_SIRGAS_2000.shp"))
```

The following error appears:

```
Error in readOGR(unz(temp, "gasoduto_SIRGAS_2000.shp")) : 
  is.character(dsn) is not TRUE
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data

Comment: What have you attempted? `download.file(.)` and then `unzip(.)` should work. If you didn't know that a function named `unzip` exists in R's `utils` package (installed by default), then you can search for packages/functions with `??unzip` (two question marks) and it'll inform you of what it finds among your installed packages.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! I tried the following: `temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/ac61a729b3856112bcb100f4dfb2c900565fdb54/gasoduto1.zip",temp)
con <- readOGR(unz(temp, "gasoduto1/gasoduto_SIRGAS_2000.shp"))`. But it did not work. I'd like to unzip, then read the file. shp.

Comment: @Antonio If yu did a search (and one always does a search before posting) and you found some answers, then you should have posted the code and the results of your efforts. If the nominated duplicate doesn't address the question, then post what you coded and the problems you see.

Comment: Sorry @IRTFM, you right! I adjusted the question.

Comment: (1) Try that URL but in a regular web browser. (2) Note that it takes you to an HTML page (which, if you check your `temp` file, is what it is: HTML). (3) Click on the `Download` button. If you want to have a URL that works without needing the brower, right-click and "Copy link". (4) Run `unzip(temp, list=TRUE)` and see that the filenames have no leading path. (5) Try `readOGR(unz(temp, "gasoduto_SIRGAS_2000.shp"))` and see that `readOGR` doesn't like file connections. I don't use `readOGR` so I don't know how best to continue (I tried extracting the file and opening normally, failed).