How do you import UCI dataset to R without downloading?
I want to import data from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/312/dow_jones_index. I don't know how to import data from the new version of the site.
In the past I've been able to do
ds <- read.csv(file = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00451/dataR2.csv', 
               header = TRUE)

but I don;t understand how to do that here. How do I import to R without downloading a zip file?

I'm not quite sure what you mean. How would R read the data without downloading it? Do you mean you want an automated way to download it and unzip it, or you want to make sure the file is deleted after you unzip it, or something else?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data

temp <- tempfile(); download.file("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/312/dow+jones+index.zip", temp); ds < read_csv(temp); unlink(temp)

Turns out you can't get to the data file directly, you need to download the zip file then unzip it, then read the table.
# URL
url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00312/dow_jones_index.zip"

# Download and unzip the dataset
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, temp)
unzip(temp, exdir = ".")
unlink(temp)  # Remove temporary file


# Import dataset into a dataframe
df <- read.table("dow_jones_index.data", sep = ',')

# View the first few rows of the dataframe
head(df)

